# Call external javaScript function into XSLT file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angular, xslt

I am trying to call an external javaScript function in XSLT file,the function will be called when i click on the image element.

The XSLT file is as bellow:

```
 <xsl:template match="link|para//link">
    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <!--OpenPopupDetailsTexte('<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>', 1);-->
        <!--alert();-->
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'n'">Note circulaire</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'm'">Modification</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'd'">D&#233;cret d application</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'ma'">Abrogation</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 't'">Renvoi au texte</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'a'">Arr&#234;t&#233; minist&#233;riel</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="text() = 'mc'">Texte compl&#233;tant cette disposition</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">/assets/projets/images/<xsl:value-of select=". "/>.gif</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

the name of my external function is **OpenPopupDetailsTexte**.

the results in HTML is :

```
<a href="unsafe:&#10;        javascript:OpenPopupDetailsTexte('cgitva_T19_N1', 1)&#10;      " title="Note circulaire"><img src="/assets/projets/images/n.gif" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are not calling an external javascript function in your XSLT. You are simply outputting text which will just happen to be parsed as Javascript when the resultant output is processed in a browser.

Anyway, you need to wrap the relevant javascript text in `xsl:text` to prevent line breaks being included. (Whitespace won't be stripped in XSLT if there are non-whitespace characters in the same node)

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:text>javascript:OpenPopupDetailsTexte('<xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
    <xsl:text>', 1);</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

Or, better still, use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)...

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopupDetailsTexte('{@href}', 1);">
```

So, the expressions in curly braces represent an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally. (Also note there is no need to use `xsl:element` to create the element, when the name is going to be static).

Comment: Should be some event handler attribute like `<a onclick="OpenPopupDetailsTexte('{@href}', 1);" ...>` if you want the script to be called by the browser. Or for a `href` attribute you would need to use a `javascript:` URL `<a href="javascript: void OpenPopupDetailsTexte('{@href}', 1);">`.

Comment: Ah yes. Good point. I've amended my answer to use the `javascript:` prefix in this case.

Comment: yes it works for me, but i'm using Angular, when i click to call this function, `i get this link ```href="unsafe:javascript:OpenPopupDetailsTexte('cgitva_T19_N1', 1);"``` when i remove the unsafe it's work.